# Android TextView align right

Tags: android, css, android-layout, android-listview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postedBy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/postedBy"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#00aadd"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

I'm trying create 'posted by name' under a news article where it should be aligned right. At this moment the username is where it should be but I cannot get the other textview to the left of it. Note: layout_toLeftOf="@id/username" isn't working.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is the parent of these `TextView`s? That's very important. Show the full xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout_toLeftOf should work inside a RelativeLayout :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postedBy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/postedBy"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/username"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#00aadd"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: @user2103237 you used @id/username and it was only after that you defined the view with the id username. It works when you use @+id/username (notice the plus)